# SQL Server 2008 services error on account

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration

I installed SQL Server Enterprise, but can't get it to work. It is a stand alone, on a laptop for development purposes. No network is involved, no other users. The OS is windows 7.

Now, I keep receiving eventId 7000, which means that access is denied for the user (the user was Network Services). So, after reading up on it, I kind of got the idea that a user account should be created with minimal privileges. So, off I went and added a user, SQLservices. In the SQL Server Configuration Manager I right clicked SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER), and in the properties I added my new user.

Well, here's mister eventId 7000 again. I don't get what I am doing wrong. Also, this new user ends up on my start-up screen. I don't think I want that... I mean, it would be weird to have x number of users crowding up my start-up screen just because I created those for my windows services...

The error I get when I add the user in SQL Server Configuration Manager is as follows: Permission Denied. [0x80070005]

Helps!

Comment: Are you able to connect to your instance via Management Studio?

Comment: No, that's how this whole thing started. Nothing happened there, so I looked in sql server configuration manager and saw that MSSQL had not started (thought it was set to start automatic) and the same for sql agent.

Answer (score 0):

Does the account in which the service is running have rights to start a service and access the folders where the program and data files are? Did you do a plain Jane install, or custom data directories and such?

Comment: No custom data, a plain jane. When installing I had instructions along with it and chose network services as the account to run everything under. Because I couldn't connect with SSMS I looked at the services in sql server configuration manager. There I saw that the MSSQL service had not started, as wel as the agent, though they are set to start up automatic. Started to look on the web for anything I could've done wrong I decided to create an account with the least privileges. I did this by creating a user account. This seemed to be too easy, so it's probably wrong...